# crossdomain issue with loading only SWF files from azure cloud storage blob

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, azure, cdn

I am having trouble loading .swf files to my flash app off my cloudstorage account on azure. images and videos load fine but .swf files return this error:

```
SecurityDomain 'http://localhost/' tried to access incompatible context 'http://[---].blob.core.windows.net/content/swf/Lib_En.swf'
```

this is my crossdomain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<cross-domain-policy>  
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />  
</cross-domain-policy>
```

In case you are wondering:
I have the correct mime-type on my crossdomain file.
This is the only error that my Main SWF generates.
I am 100% certain that the SWF is loading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lib_En.swf should allow other domains to access it. Somewhere in the code of Lib_En.swf put the below line.

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

Build it again and upload.

more about this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain%28%29